# Background image loads after every other element in react-native app

Tags: android, ios, css, image, react-native

When building my app via `react-native run-android --variant=release` I can see that all my resources are loaded from the start, except my background image. This created a very disrupting transition from one screen to another (Although I'm in particular talking about the case where I go from splash screen to login screen). I was wondering what I could do to make sure all resources are loaded from the start.

Here is how I've set up my components:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={[styles.background, styles.container]}
          source={background}
          resizeMode='cover'
        >
         ...bunch of components

        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It's the Image component that loads after all other components. Could it be that it's much higher resolution than the other images? I'm using a splash screen which should stop as soon as the javascript in my app has finished loading so that shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: Is the image remote or local?

Comment: The image is local